# Bounty claimed by answer with just URL in it on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I started a bounty for the first time for a question. Someone immediately posted an answer which had only a link in it and referenced link, and also it didn't have anything about answer. And it seems like the person has gotten bounty points rendering bounty unavailable for someone who could have answered my question.

Is there a way I can remove bounty? Because clearly I have not received any answer :(

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150728/how-to-select-ui-component-packages-on-npm-for-project/43550004#43550004

Comment: Please read about bounties before coming and claiming totally wrong things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is based on a total misunderstanding of the bounty system.

Comment: The link question no longer even has a bounty because it wasn't even on topic.  *Putting on a bounty on a question does not prevent it from a moderator from putting it on hold by the way.*

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I phrased by statement incorrectly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It seems a bit backward to close a question because the asker misunderstands the situation, especially when the actual facts of the case are fairly easily discoverable. An answer that corrects this misconception would seem at once straightforward to post, and potentially useful in similar cases.

Comment: The question being discussed seems to have been deleted from SO.

Comment: @NathanTuggy usually I would agree with you. However, this one here is extreme case. Think of a tourist coming to a police station and filing a report, saying "I went to a book shop and bought a book for $50, paying in cash. I arrived home and found the book is in foreign language. I feel deceived and demand a refund!". Now obviously, the tourist could just **look in the book** to see it's in foreign language in the first place, before buying it. It is not the police job to explain this trivial thing to him, neither to refund his money. This one here isn't *exactly* the same, but close enough.

Comment: @shadow wizard - now thats extreme analogy. u seem to accuse me as if i did something on purpose adn getting some benefit out of it.

Comment: stackoverflow used to be far more accepting initially and i believe their policy was good to keep quality of answers and keep away reputation hunters. is dis question that bad in your opinion?

Comment: @saurabh not really. That tourist didn't do anything bad on purpose, and nothing bad at all. Just made a mistake, as you did, but it's simply not on topic here to fix that mistake.

Comment: If you talk about your question on Stack Overflow then SO also got its own meta, but in general the scope of Stack Overflow changed drastically over the years. These days anything asking for book/tool recommendation is off topic there.

Comment: sorry if im rude but opinions , stupid questions generate information. and information is definitely useful for industry  revolving around it. couldnt care less about bounty or rep, just wanted my question answered by some n i know for sure there are so many stackoverfow users helping ,https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Stack-Overflow-have-such-a-strict-community

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy thanks understanding situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer hasn't had the bounty claimed because it hasn't been accepted so someone else can come along and post an answer for the bounty. You would just need to mark it as the right answer (click the tick button) for them to earn the bounty.

Comment: It's much more than that: the bounty was just started, it can't be awarded for 24 hours. Answer was downvoted. And the question itself was off topic to begin with...

Comment: question on stackoverflow was about code quality in angular area with respect to using components available through npm. would appreciate some edits to question or better place to ask questions related to code quality

Comment: @Daniel James thanks for answering, appreciate it